# Ionic input field does not move to next field automatically

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im using ionic 3 for my mobile application, I have some issues with my input fields which do not move automatically to the next field. For example when I click the first input filed and fill the first one, the cursor does not move to the next field. How to do that correctly?

```
 <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item >
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1" tabindex="1"   ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1"  tabindex="2"  ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1"  tabindex="3"  ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1"  tabindex="4"   ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

    </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following approach, there could be better approaches i'm just sharing what i know.

What i am doing here is setting a reference of the next element (eg: `#b`), and on keyup event i am passing that reference to my function in `.ts` file which only calls the `.setFocus()` on the referenced element.

```
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item >
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" (keyup)="moveFocus(b)"  ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1"  tabindex="2" #b (keyup)="moveFocus(c)"  ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1"  tabindex="3" #c (keyup)="moveFocus(d)"  ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1"  tabindex="4" #d  ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

    </ion-grid>
```

.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'page-home',
          templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        export class HomePage {

          constructor() {

          }

          moveFocus(nextElement) {
            nextElement.focus();
          }

        }
```

Comment: Sir its not work for me , i have this error `TypeError: _co.moveFocus is not a function`

Comment: Sorry my mistake i named the function in `.ts` file wrong. Just change the function name in `.ts` file from `moveToNext()` to `moveFocus()`.

Comment: For Ionic 4, use nextElemnt.setFocus()

Comment: How do I get the values from there input fields as ngModel is not working for these ?

Comment: keyup.enter for the event or it will always go next

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with the (keyup) or (keydown) events. There is also documentation available on the angular docs that talks about forms and user Input.

**HTML**

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

**.ts**

```
onKey(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the `nextElementSibling` , you can use the `Keyup` event to achieve this , here is the Pseudo code

Add keyup event to the event fields as follows `(keyup)="keytab($event)"`

```
keytab(event){
    let element = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling; // get the sibling element

    if(element == null)  // check if its null
        return;
    else
        element.focus();   // focus if not null
}
```

In order to make it more clear manner you can create a directive also as follows

**tabindex.directive.ts:**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TextInput } from 'ionic-angular';

@Directive({
    selector: '[yourTabindex]'
})
export class TabindexDirective {

    constructor(private inputRef: TextInput) { }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onInputChange(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (code === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.inputRef.focusNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include this directive in Modules page and you can use it on your input fields as follows ,as a sample:

```
<ion-input type="tel" placeholder="*" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" yourTabindex   ></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "scrollAssist: true" and "autoFocusAssist: true" to app.module in the @ngModule would solve this problem.

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
        scrollAssist: true,
        autoFocusAssist: true
    })
],
```